# Is it possible to use "on a related subject" as an introductory phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

I've heard the phrase in Hannibal (the series). Is it commonly used?

Does it mean the same as "in the same context"?

Comment: Can you include the text in question, in an edit to YOUR question?  I suspect that it's not actually an **Introductory phrase** at all.

Comment: Yes it means roughly (but not exactly) the same as "in the same context". The phrase is often used to introduce a change of direction in a conversation (or essay).  On a related subject, questions like this should include evidence of the research you've done.

Comment: Are you asking as an English language learner? If so you might find our sister site more useful for such questions: [ell.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of this phrase most likely comes from excerpts like the following:

*“On a related subject, Signore Pazzi, I must confess to you: I'm giving serious thought to eating your wife.” - Thomas Harris, Hannibal.*

This is dialogue and as such the rules of correct grammar are more forgiving. To your second question, the interpretation of the meaning behind the phrase, I would argue that it's pretty much self-evident. It means we're changing to a subject that is different but related to the previous one.

In the above example, however, we can only assume that the phrase is intended to be pithy, sarcastic line of dialogue for the main character. It seems unlikely that the previous subject was really related to the eating of Pazzi's wife.

Hope this helps.

http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/334203-on-a-related-subject-signore-pazzi-i-must-confess-to